# How to create a kentico form that does not store the response

Tags: forms, kentico

Is there any way in Kentico to have a user submit a form and then email the response but not actually save the answer to the related table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned the emails from Kentico rely on the record being written to the DB before they trigger.  Furthermore (unless I'm just unlucky) the only values you have access to are those stored in the table.  I had thought that maybe you could mark the offending fields as *Field without database representation*, but sadly, the fields you may want will all be null - so best not to go down that route.

I took a slightly different approach to @trevor-j-fayas in that I used the **`BizFormItemEvents.Insert.Before`** event so that there is no trace of any log.  It's a short hop from there to make use of an email template to make things look good.  So my code looked as follows:

```
using CMS;
using CMS.DataEngine;
using CMS.EmailEngine;
using System;

[assembly: RegisterModule(typeof(FormGlobalEvents))]
public class FormGlobalEvents : Module
{
    public FormGlobalEvents() : base("FormGlobalEvents")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnInit()
    {
        CMS.OnlineForms.BizFormItemEvents.Insert.Before += Insert_Before;
    }

    private void Insert_Before(object sender, CMS.OnlineForms.BizFormItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var email = new EmailMessage();
        email.From = e.Item.GetStringValue("ContactEmail", "null@foo.com");
        email.Recipients = "no-reply@foo.com";
        email.Subject = "Test from event handler (before save)";
        email.PlainTextBody = "test" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

        EmailSender.SendEmail(email);

        e.Cancel();
    }
}
```

To me, it seems cleaner to not insert the record in the first place than delete it, but obviously that autoresponder etc. will only kick in automatically if you do save the record, so the choice is yours and ultimately depends on your preference.

Comment: This is indeed a way, but if there is no other specific requirement for Forms functionality apart from sending an email, then it doesn't even have to be a form at all. In my opinion the cleanest and easiest way to accomplish this is to create a custom webpart which will display some input fields and a button that will send an email.

Comment: Yep, js2 - I'd agree it could be a web part with a 'normal' form and a button as you say.  The benefit of using the is primarily in using the Form builder to sort out the fields and validation etc.

Comment: I'd second @mnield approach for the same reason, let the client use the form builder which has all the built in features like validation and proper data type (even though it's not inserting data).  On top of this you can create a custom table to have the user manage this on their own with a single global event handler checking a custom table for the forms they have entered as well as send to and from email addresses.  Do a lookup of the custom table to see if the current inserted item is a record in the custom table then use the settings there to send our email.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.  The record is stored before the email notifications and autoresponders are sent out.  Your best bet for this is to create a custom global event handler for the form submission(s) using the BizFormItemEvents.Insert.Before.  This will call the event before the actual record is stored in the database.  You can then cancel out of the event (which will not store the record) and send your email manually.

[Handling global events](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/handling-global-events)
[BizFormItemEvents Events](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/handling-global-events/reference-global-system-events#Reference-Globalsystemevents-BizFormItemEvents)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a couple different options, but the easiest is to simply delete the record after it's inserted.  Use the Global Event Hooks to capture the BizFormItemEvent insert after, if it's your form, then delete it.  Below is for Kentico 10:

```
using CMS;
using CMS.DataEngine;
using CMS.Forums;
using CMS.Helpers;
using CMS.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
// Registers the custom module into the system
[assembly: RegisterModule(typeof(CustomLoaderModule))]

public class CustomLoaderModule : Module
{
    // Module class constructor, the system registers the module under the name "CustomForums"
    public CustomLoaderModule()
        : base("CustomLoaderModule")
    {
    }

    // Contains initialization code that is executed when the application starts
    protected override void OnInit()
    {
        base.OnInit();
        CMS.OnlineForms.BizFormItemEvents.Insert.After += BizFormItem_Insert_After;


    }

    private void BizFormItem_Insert_After(object sender, CMS.OnlineForms.BizFormItemEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(e.Item.BizFormInfo.FormName)
        {
            case "YourFormNameHere":
                e.Item.Delete();
                break;
        }
    }
 }
```

The other option would be to clone and modify the Online Form Web part to take the information, manually call the email and cancel the insert, but that's a lot of work when this is quicker.

Comment: Hi Trevor, according to the comment from Brenden and your code, it suggest the record is saved to the database, sent out in an email and then deleted from the database? If that's the case then the record would be saved to the DB and end up in the SQL logs somewhere?

Cheers,

John

Comment: John, my answer states to intercept the insert BEFORE it inserts (hence the Insert.Before event) and not after the record is saved.  Read the answer again.